# Can I set up Boot Camp in a headless mac pro?

Tags: bootcamp, ssh, mac-pro

I have this headless Mac Pro in the living room. I access it from my MBP through the network, ssh and sometimes with a remote desktop solution. I use it to run data/computing.

Now I need to get Windows in; there's a piece of software that's only available there. To avoid virtualization drawbacks, I'm thinking of setting up a dual system like Boot Camp, but I've never done it, much less without a monitor.

Is it doable? (setting it up without a screen)

Comment: Do you have monitor you can temporary use to install Windows? Many modern TVs have VGA or DVI jacks. Also, what is the model/year of your Mac Pro? Which Windows version did you want to install? What is the model/year of the MBP? What other computers/OSs do you have available? What version of macOS do you have installed on the Mac Pro and MBP?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I'll have to do, use a monitor temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it doable? (setting it up without a screen)

No. Installing Boot Camp will reboot the system into the Windows installer. You will need to see the screen to complete the installation. Any remote desktop software you've set up in macOS will be unavailable in Windows, including during the Windows install process.